# Using sed in a for loop with variables and regex

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

I'm trying to build a script where a portion of it utilizes 'sed' to tag the filename onto the end of each line in that file, then dumps the output to a master list.
The part of the script giving me trouble is sed here:

```
DIR=/var/www/flatuser
FILES=$DIR/*
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "processing $f file...."
    sed -i "s/$/:$f/" $f
    cat $f >> $DIR/master.txt
done
```

The issue is that the 'sed' statement works fine outside of the for loop, but when I place it in the script, I believe it's having issues interpreting the dollar signs. I've tried nearly every combo of " and ' that I can think of to get it to interpret the variable and it continuously either puts "$f" at the end of each line, or it fails outright.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: @chepner's answer is on-point. The other thing to add to it, though, is that you need to double-quote _all_ expansions to make them safe for contents with whitespace (or glob expansions, etc)... so, for instance, `cat "$f" >>"$DIR/master.txt`.

Comment: Well, bigger point -- if you just want the names included in master.txt, you shouldn't be using `sed -i` on the original files first; doing it that way means you can't run your script more than once without adding more than one copy of the names, which is an unfortunate restriction.

Comment: OHHH I see what's wrong!! posting my answer in a second...hint it's NOT the dollar sign!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd do this like so:

```
dir=/var/www/flatuser
for f in "$dir"/*; do
  [[ $f = */master.txt ]] && continue
  while read -r; do printf '%s:%s\n' "$REPLY" "${f##*/}"; done <"$f"
done >/var/www/flatuser/master.txt
```

It doesn't modify your files in-place the way `sed -i` does, so it's safe to run more than one time (the `sed -i` version will add the names to your files in-place every time it runs, so  you'll end up with each line having more than one copy of the filename on it).

Also, `sed -i` isn't specified by POSIX, so not all operating systems will have it.

Comment: Oops. Earlier revision of this didn't actually open `$f` for input in the loop.

Comment: This answer gets me the closest to what I'm going for. I'm not married to 'sed' for this solution, it's just what I have in my limited "toolbox" ;). The only issue with this one is that it tags the full path onto the end of each line instead of just the filename. Tried fiddling with it and I dont' see where that comes from. suggestion?

Comment: I'd recommend this answer, over trying to find a delimiter for `sed`'s substitution operator that doesn't occur in `$f`.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks to everyone for all of your suggestions. I've been spinning my gears on this for too long :).

Answer (score 5):

You just need to escape the dollar sign:

```
sed -i "s/\$/:$f/" "$f"
```

so that the shell passes it literally to `sed`.

To expand on Charles Duffy's point about quoting variables:

```
DIR=/var/www/flatuser
for f in "$DIR"/*
do
    echo "processing $f file...."
    sed -i "s/\$/:${f##*/}/" "$f"
    cat "$f" >> "$DIR/master.txt"
done
```

If any file names contain a space, it's too late to do anything about it if you assign the list of file names to `$FILES`; you can no longer distinguish between spaces that belong to file names and spaces that separate file names. You could use an array instead, but it's simpler to just put the glob directly in the for loop. Here's how you would use an array:

```
DIR=/var/www/flatuser
FILES=( "$DIR"/* )
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo "processing $f file...."
    sed -i "s/\$/:${f##*/}/" "$f"
    cat "$f" >> "$DIR/master.txt"
done
```

For versions of `sed` that don't use `-i`, here's a way to explicitly handle the temp file needed to simulate in-place editing:

```
t=$(mktmp sXXXX); sed "s/\$/:$f/" "$f" > "$t"; mv "$t" "$f" && rm "$t"
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! Though, when using either of the above methods, I'm still getting sed errors. Here's what I'm seeing and maybe this will help shed some light: `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to s'`. the files it's operating on are similar to this: `abc-test1` `abc-test2`. I thought removing the hyphens in the filename would help, but I saw no change after doing that.

Comment: @pepper is right about the file name's path separator conflicting with `sed`'s delimiter. Although you can use a different delimiter, you still need to choose one that doesn't appear in `$f`, which could be tricky.

Comment: Removing directories from the value of `$f` when using it with the `sed` command removes the issue of `/` as the delimiter, as a simple file name cannot contain a `/`.

Comment: If you choose a different delimiter, I don't see why this solution would not work.

Comment: The choice of such a delimiter would always depend on the value of `$f`.

Comment: You just made me realize a huge part of my problem. echo of $f revealed `/path/to/file` -_-. Either way, even changing the separator didn't seem to help for whatever reason. Though I hope this may clear up something. Thanks again for helping an amateur find his way, haha

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NOT the dollar sign. It's that the variable $f contains a "/" character, and sed is using that to separate expressions. Try using "@" as the separator.

```
DIR=/var/www/flatuser
FILES=$DIR/*
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "processing $f file...."
    sed -i s@"$"@:"$f"@ $f
    cat $f >> $DIR/master.txt
done
```

Comment: Now you *do* have a quoting issue, though, because `$@` is a special shell parameter :)

Comment: sed statement is in quotes, though I'll edit it to move the quotes and be sure this works

Comment: Double-quotes; parameter expansion applies.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing out the separator earlier to no success. @CharlesDuffy's answer gets me the closest to the end result, thought it puts the full path at the end of the line instead of just the filename

Comment: @SteveHNH: I modified Charle's answer to limit the addition to the simple file name, rather than the full path

Comment: @pepper: You're just trading one problem for another here. This will not work for file names containing spaces (although the original assignment to `FILES` makes that problem insurmountable regardless of what you do with the for loop).

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it so that it will work for filenames that contain spaces. Honestly, I was just trying to correct the error that he was getting with sed, and don't personally use spaces in filenames.

Comment: Good point @pepper, however in this case I know the filenames ahead of time and none will ever contain a space. It is good to note in case someone else finds and wants to use this though :)

Comment: This solution also adds the entire file path. To make that not the case, it would be better to change $f to $(basename $f) before passing it to sed.

Answer (score 0):

it's old, but maybe it helps someone.
Why not basename the file to get rid of leading directory

```
DIR=/var/www/flatuser
FILES=( "$DIR"/* )
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo "processing $f file...."
    b=`basename $f`
    sed -i "s/\$/:${b##*/}/" "$b"
    cat "$f" >> "$DIR/master.txt"
done
```

not tested ...